# Simple client-server communication not working

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock2

The code is overall very simple but it won't work, it'll throw an exception of `char at memory location 0x00EEEE74.` but there is no possible place (as far as I can see) for me going out of memory bounds.

I run, overall, two programs - one client and one server and the server is the one throwing the error.
``
The crash is upon the program calling `Receive` from the server's function `AcceptConnections`, it points to the end of the function (the last brackets) and says that this was the next action to perform.

Here is the code for both:

```
//server-main.cpp
int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    Server s("6666");

    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Client Main:

```
int main()
{
    WSAData wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);

    Client c(SERVER_ADDR, PORT);
    string ToSend("Magshimim Test");
    char buf[1025];
    int bytesRecieved = 0;
    cout << "Bytes sent: " << c.Send((void*)ToSend.c_str(), ToSend.length()) << endl;

    cout << "Recieving message from server..." << endl;
    bytesRecieved = c.Receive((void*)buf, 1024);
    cout << "Bytes Recieved: " << bytesRecieved << endl;
    if(bytesRecieved > 0)
    {
        buf[bytesRecieved] = '\0';
        cout << "Message recieved: " << buf << endl;
    }

    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

The main are Send and Receive (the same for both server and client - flags' default value is 0):

```
int Server::Send(void* buf, int len, int flags)
{
    send(this->_socket, (const char*)&len, sizeof(int), 0); //sending the length of the message
    return send(this->_socket, (const char*)buf, len, flags); //sending the message itself
}

int Server::Receive(void* buf, int maxlen, int flags)
{
    int len_to_recv = 0;
    recv(this->_socket, (char*)&len_to_recv, sizeof(int), 0);
    if (maxlen != 0 && len_to_recv > maxlen) //0 symbolizes unlimited len and we check if there's not too much information
    {
        throw "Receive: Too much information";
    }

    return recv(this->_socket, (char*)buf, len_to_recv, flags);
/*Points here->>>>>*/}
```

And the other one that is sending the Exception is the server's c'tor, scroll down to "AcceptConnections" (which is called by the c'tor) and the `Receive` call is the one making the exception.

```
Server::Server(string Port) : _details(NULL)
{
    struct addrinfo hints;
    this->_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (_socket < 0)
        throw "Invalid socket";
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    if (getaddrinfo(NULL, Port.c_str(), &hints, &this->_details) != 0)
    {
        throw "GetAddrInfo failed";
    }

    if (bind(this->_socket, this->_details->ai_addr, this->_details->ai_addrlen) != 0)
    {
        throw "Bind Unsuccessful";
    }

    freeaddrinfo(this->_details);

    this->AcceptConnections();
}

void Server::AcceptConnections()
{
    if (listen(this->_socket, SOMAXCONN) != 0)
        throw "Listen Unsuccessful";
    char buf[1025];
    char* ans = "Accepted";
    SOCKET client;
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    int addrlen = sizeof(client_addr);

    client = accept(this->_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &addrlen);
    closesocket(this->_socket);
    this->_socket = client;

    cout << "A connection was accepted." << endl; // It prints this

    /*THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM OCCURS.
    THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM OCCURS.
    IT ENTERS THE FUNCTION, THEN UPON ENDING IT (AFTER THE RETURN), THROWING       AN EXCEPTION*/
    int recvBytes = this->Receive(buf, MY_MAX_LEN); // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    if (recvBytes <= 0)
    {
        throw "Client disconnected";
    }
    this->Send(ans, strlen(ans));

    closesocket(client);
    closesocket(this->_socket);
}
```

This code is almost step by step after the MSDN tutorial, for some reason, though, when I try to manage it with the classes, it goes wrong :(

Any idea why?

Comment: Please provide a ___[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)___

Comment: You have presented C++ code.  C++ is not C.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Indeed, my bad.

Comment: Well, did you trace into the Receive() function?  What is 'MY_MAX_LEN' and why is buf not declared as 'char buf[MY_MAX_LEN]' ?

Comment: Ohwait, what is this?  'recv(this->_socket, (char*)&len_to_recv, sizeof(int), 0);'   Doesn't reference buf at all.  2nd parameter is grossly wrong,  You are blowing the received data all over the stack.

Comment: @MartinJames Hmm, where is the problem at that ? I'm getting the size of the buffer that is about to be sent - if you'd look at Send you'll see that I also send the size of the data before I send the data itself. Where exactly can you see me 'blowing' the received data if I'm asking only for the size of int?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever else might be wrong, this has to be:

```
recv(this->_socket, (char*)&len_to_recv, sizeof(int), 0);
```

Did you mean:

```
len_to_recv=recv(this->_socket, buf, sizeof(int), 0);
```

[edit]  the above is crap.

You should not assume that the recv() actually receives all 4/8 bytes in one call, (though it probably will, it's not guaranteed). Also, endianness? Prolly not an issue if you are running on localhost for testing, but..

Comment: No, I didn't. I meant to receive the length of the buffer that is ABOUT to be sent, not what is sent now. Look at 'Send' function and notice that I send the length (as an int) of the data and then the data itself so I won't be forced to use chunks if I don't want to. max_len also specifies the length of the buffer, so I won't cause a buffer overflow

Comment: Oh, OK, so this answer is rubbish:(   Maybe I'm over-tired.  Nevertheless, you should not assume that the recv() actually receives all 4/8 bytes in one call, (though it probably will, it's not guaranteed).  Also, endianness...